# Tailwind: Parent dynamically fit child height

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an image as the header and text as well as button that need to appear on top of the header image. What i want to achieve is, in the small media screen, i want to make the height of image header change accordingly to the height of the text as well as the button.

This is basically what I try to achieve here. (Taken from an example site):

[image: Example taken from another site]

But my code below give me this:
[image]

```
    const styles = {
       backgroundImage: `url(${banner})`,
       backgroundSize: 'cover',
       backgroundPosition: 'right',
    };
<section className="container-banner relative">
            <div className='gambar h-[50vh]' style={styles} >
                <div className='absolute inset-0 bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-60 md:bg-opacity-0'>

                    <div className="flex absolute top-28 md:left-1/2 md:transform md:-translate-x-1/2 md:text-left md:w-[1400px] md:top-44">
                        <div className='flex-col justify-center mx-auto md:flex-1 w-10/12 md:mx-auto'>
                            <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold text-gray-100 md:text-text md:text-6xl md:leading-tight '>Pakar dalam merealisasikan perabot impian anda.</h1>
                            <p className='mt-4 text-sm text-gray-100 md:mx-auto md:text-text md:leading-relaxed md:text-2xl'>Kami menghidupkan idea anda dengan kepakaran kami dalam kerja kayu tersuai. Hubungi kami hari ini untuk bermula!</p>
                            <a href="/contact-us"><button className='group font-semibold px-7 py-4 mt-8 bg-ascent-default text-black rounded-lg md:text-2xl hover:bg-ascent-dark duration-150'>Contact Us <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} className='text-base group-hover:translate-x-1 duration-150' /></button></a>
                        </div>
                        <div className='w-0 bg-red md:flex-1'></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Some try and error method i have tried is add minHeight and maxHeight to 100%, but it doesn't work. Btw, please ignore the messy tailwind media query since i'm still in the learning process of the responsive. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider not using `position: absolute`. By not using `position: absolute`, the element would be within the layout flow and the `<div>` with the background can adjust its height to its inner content.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<section class="container-banner relative">
  <div class='gambar' style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000); background-size: cover; background-position: right">
    <div class='bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-60 md:bg-opacity-0'>

      <div class="relative flex pt-28 md:left-1/2 md:transform md:-translate-x-1/2 md:text-left md:w-[1400px] md:pt-44">
        <div class='flex-col justify-center mx-auto md:flex-1 w-10/12 md:mx-auto'>
          <h1 class='text-2xl font-bold text-gray-100 md:text-text md:text-6xl md:leading-tight '>Pakar dalam merealisasikan perabot impian anda.</h1>
          <p class='mt-4 text-sm text-gray-100 md:mx-auto md:text-text md:leading-relaxed md:text-2xl'>Kami menghidupkan idea anda dengan kepakaran kami dalam kerja kayu tersuai. Hubungi kami hari ini untuk bermula!</p>
          <a href="/contact-us"><button class='group font-semibold px-7 py-4 mt-8 bg-ascent-default text-black rounded-lg md:text-2xl hover:bg-ascent-dark duration-150'>Contact Us <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} class='text-base group-hover:translate-x-1 duration-150'>FontAwesomeIcon</FontAwesomeIcon></button></a>
        </div>
        <div class='w-0 bg-red md:flex-1'></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow, that's works! Thank you. Is it not recommended to use absolute?

Comment: *I* would not recommend using absolute at least in this particular situation.